# BB Code versus restricted HTML

Tags: security

Are there any security risks in allowing(whitelist only) pure markup tags such as a, b, i, etc in post submission?

BB code seems like a heavy solution to the problem of injecting code and whitelisting "safe" html tags seems easier then going through all the parsing and conversion that bb code requires.

I have found that many bb code libraries have issues with nested elements(is this because they use a FSA or regex, instead of a proper parser?) and blockquote or fieldset are properly parsed by the web browser.

Any and all opinions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is something everyone seems to get wrong, while it is so simple.

**Use a parser**

It doesn't matter whether you use markdown, html, bbcode, whatever.

**Use a parser.** A real parser. Not a bunch of regexes.

The parser gives you a syntaxtree. From the syntaxtree you derive the html (still as a tree of objects). Clean the tree (using a whitelist), print the html.

Using html as syntax is perfectly fine. Just don't try to clean it with regexes.

Comment: Something like html.parser in Python or Nokogiri for Ruby?

Comment: Anything is fine, as long as at some point you can manipulate it as objects, and then print out html based on the objects, and not on the source (so your users cannot exploit strange html parsing behaviour of browsers). But nokogiri seems possible, since someone based a whitelisting parser on it: http://wonko.com/post/sanitize .

Comment: Last word of advice, at some unit tests to see if the sanitation works, just to make sure, and secondly, when you ever have a breach, you can add it to the tests (though this shouldn't be possible with the prevented approach, but I'm a big proponent of defense in layers: assume everything can fail)

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with using HTML as long as you:

1. Use a proper HTML parser to process the input.
2. Whitelist the tags so that only things you want get through.
3. Whitelist the attributes on the tags. This includes parsing and whitelist things inside `style` attributes if you want to allow `style` (and, of course, use a real CSS parser for the `style` attributes).
4. Rewrite the HTML while you parse it.

The last point is mostly about getting consistent and correct HTML output. Your parser should take care of figuring out the usual confusion (such as incorrectly nested tags) that you find in hand written HTML.

Comment: Be really careful when allowing css, because it's really easy to do XSS there if you don't properly whitelist and parse it.

Comment: @markijbema: That's why I said to whitelist that too and, of course, use a real CSS parser.

Comment: @Befuddled: Pay it forward and help someone else later :)